# Why All the Dataflows don't appear in purview after a Debug?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-purview

I've a pipeline in the Azure Datafactory that's linked to the Azure purview to monitor changes.
Once I debug the pipeline the copy activity and the Dataflow appeared in the Azure purview.
Now I altered the dataflow a little and run the pipeline.
But now only the Copy activity is updated in the Purview but not the Dataflow.
Can Anyone explain why?? :/

Comment: what did you altered the data flow? Did you changed the source?

Comment: I've added some activities like look up

Comment: did you change the data storage?